# Javascript onbeforerequest redirect url does not work

Tags: javascript, redirect, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I was trying to create a Mozilla Firefox URL redirection addon however when I created it myself using the code on the mozilla firefox page about OnBeforeRequest url redirection, the addon didn't work. So I decided to copy and paste the code from the Mozilla website guide to see if I wrote the code wrong, however the same thing happens. It cancels the requests correctly however whenever I try redirecting urls using the redirectUrl option, it doesn't work

My code is as follows:

**manifest.json**

```
{

  "description": "Demonstrating webRequests",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "webRequest-demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "@addontest"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  }

}
```

**main.js**

```
var pattern = "https://mdn.mozillademos.org/*";

function redirect(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Redirecting: " + requestDetails.url);
  return {
    redirectUrl: "https://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ldbj01lZiP1qe0eclo1_500.gif"
    // cancel:true
  };
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  redirect,
  {urls:[pattern], types:["image"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

In the **main.js**, if I were to comment out the

```
redirectUrl: "https://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ldbj01lZiP1qe0eclo1_500.gif"
```

and uncomment the following line:

```
cancel:true
```

the code works correctly and the requests are canceled, however its just whenever I try to redirect it, it stops working.

Can anyone help please? It's been bugging me for a few days now and I just can't seem to find anything to fix it. There's no errors or anything in the firefox console (CTRL + SHIFT + J) or in the firebug console

Comment: Is this for a Firefox add on or something? If so, you may want to consider adding the appropriate tag. This is not something that would work in any normal web page...

Comment: Yes it is, sorry i'll add that now